# What are the available modes in beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

In `beamer` class for presentations we can use the `\mode` command to control what part of our text belongs to which mode. My question is how many mode are available for use?

Comment: 3, AFAIK: `presentation`, `article`, `handout`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From section *21.3 Details on Modes* in [The Beamer class User Guide for version 3.36](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.21.3):

> When beamer typesets your text, it is always in one of the following five modes:
>
> - **beamer** is the default mode.
> - **second** is the mode used when a slide for an optional second screen is being typeset.
> - **handout** is the mode for creating handouts.
> - **trans** is the mode for creating transparencies.
> - **article** is the mode when control has been transferred to another class, like article.cls. Note that the mode is also article if control is transferred to, say, book.cls.
>
> In addition to these modes, beamer recognizes the following names for modes sets:
>
> - **all** refers to all modes.
> - **presentation** refers to the first four modes, that is, to all modes except for the article mode.

[image]

Comment: From 21.3 *Details on Modes* in *User Guide for version 3.36* (March 8, 2015).