# Beamertheme is ignoring handout mode

Tags: beamer

I am preparing a talk and compiled my beamer slides with the handout option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,handout,final]{beamer}
\usetheme{TUC}
```

My file `beamerthemeTUC.sty` says the following:

```
\mode<all>{
  \usefonttheme {TUC}
  \usecolortheme{TUC}
  \useinnertheme{TUC}
}

\mode<presentation>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC}
}

\mode<handout>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC-handout}
```

But the log file says:

> (/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/tex/latex/TUC/tuc-cd/TUC-Beamer/beamerthemeTUC.sty
>   (/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/tex/latex/TUC/tuc-cd/TUC-Beamer/beamerfontthemeTUC.sty)
>   (/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/tex/latex/TUC/tuc-cd/TUC-Beamer/beamercolorthemeTUC.sty)
>   (/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/tex/latex/TUC/tuc-cd/TUC-Beamer/beamerinnerthemeTUC.sty)
>   (/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/tex/latex/TUC/tuc-cd/TUC-Beamer/beamerouterthemeTUC.sty)
>   (/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/tex/latex/TUC/tuc-cd/TUC-Beamer/beamerouterthemeTUC-handout.sty

As you can see, besides the fact, that option `handout` is set, LaTeX loads both style files.

Of course, I have tried different orders, without any change.

What was my mistake?

(The normal TUC theme uses navigation elements, which I wanted to suppress in the printed handout.  It is of absolutely no use in that case ...)

Answer (score 1):

The `presentation` mode also contains the `handout` mode, see this graphic from the beamer user guide:

[image]

If you want something only in the "real" presentation, but not in handout, use `beamer` mode:

```
\documentclass[
handout
]{beamer}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{beamerouterthemeTUC.sty}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{beamerouterthemeTUC-handout.sty}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{beamerthemeTUC.sty}

\mode<handout>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC-handout}
}

\mode<beamer>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC}
}


\end{filecontents*}

\usetheme{TUC}



\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

If the `handout` theme is loaded after the `presentation` theme, you can however overwrite it:

```
\documentclass[
%handout
]{beamer}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{beamerouterthemeTUC.sty}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{beamerouterthemeTUC-handout.sty}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{beamerthemeTUC.sty}
\mode<presentation>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC}
}

\mode<handout>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC-handout}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usetheme{TUC}



\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sam, you are partially correct, as you can overwrite some beamer variables.  But the files I use, contain some other stuff, like defining logos, which depend on the choosen language ... When loading both the normal theme and the handout-theme, I get error messages, because of defining things, which are already defined.

Answer (score 1):

Sam Carter pointed out in her answer a special detail, which was new to me.

The solution to my problem would be, to use the following code in my `beamerthemeTUC.sty`file.

```
\mode<handout>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC-handout}
}

\mode<beamer|second|trans>{
  \useoutertheme{TUC}
}
```

Sam Carter gave the important hint, that the mode `presentation` contains both `handout` and `beamer`.  Meanwhile I found this  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263442/120477 and learned the following:

This following modes exist:

- `beamer`
- `second`
- `trans`
- `handout`
- `article`

Than we have some mode "groups":

- `presentation` which contains: `beamer`, `second`, `trans` **and** `handout`
- `all` which contains all of the above modes.

I was wrong, as I thought, `presentation` would not include the handouts.

By using the `mode<beamer|second|trans>` I can select every presentation mode except handout, which is, what I wanted.