# Beamer mode and input

Tags: beamer, input, mode

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
    \mode*
    
    \mode<all>{
    
    \input{input1.tex}
    
    \input{input2.tex}
    
    }
\end{document}
```

Surprisingly, the second file that is input, is not compiled. Why is this the case?
A modification to

```
\mode<all>{ \input{input1.tex} }

\mode<all>{ \input{input2.tex} }
```

seems to work, but I find it a bit surprising that the previous notion does not work.

Now, after samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz reply, I am more confused. The edit to the following works also:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
    \mode*
    
    \mode<all>
    
    \input{input1.tex}
    
    \input{input2.tex}
    
    
\end{document}
```

So after removing the `{}` it works even without the suggested `makeatlatter`-extension from samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.
Why is this the case? So is that true because the `\mode` command cannot be limited to a particular area in the code with brackets?

Comment: `\mode*
    \mode<all>    
    \input{input1.tex}
    \input{input2.tex}
    \mode*`, see the example on p. 207 of the beamer user guide

Comment: related: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/480

Comment: Thanks. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263440/what-are-the-available-modes-in-beamer helped also a bit in understanding these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an academic exercise, you could add `\input` to the list of macros which are not ignored in `ignorenonframetext` mode, and you would get the second frame (be careful, this will probably cause some kind of problem, because a similar change to beamer was reverted  https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0701322e7399290768a1c1a73c72960f7745dec3):

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{input1.tex}
\begin{frame}
1
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{input2.tex}
\begin{frame}
2
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}


\makeatletter
\def\beamer@treat{%
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\frame\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\lecture\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\note\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\appendix\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\input\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\beamer@appendixwrite\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\againframe\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\section\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\subsection\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\subsubsection\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\part\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\article\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\mode\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\common\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\presentation\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\begin\let\next=\beamer@checkbeginframe\fi
  \ifx\beamer@nexttoken\end\let\next=\beamer@checkenddoc\fi
  \next}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \mode*
    
    
    \mode<all>{
    
    \input{input1.tex}
    
    \input{input2.tex}
    
    }
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for this? The referenced page in the beamer manual seems not to enlighten me much. I edit also my question a bit in this respect.